# Get ID and row from foreign key ID which was derived from session username

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to get an ID and a row called info to be shown based of the username.

I have a users table:

```
TABLE users (
id       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                 NOT NULL,
username TEXT    NOT NULL
                 UNIQUE,
password TEXT    NOT NULL
```

and an infos table that has the userid as an FK:

```
TABLE infos (
infoid  INTEGER NOT NULL
                  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
info    TEXT    NOT NULL,
productid INTEGER REFERENCES product (productid) 
                  NOT NULL,
userid    INTEGER REFERENCES users (id) 
                  NOT NULL
```

I have managed to get the username from the session and the userid:

```
// get username
$name = $_SESSION['username'];
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :name");
$stmt->execute(["name" => $name]);
$r = $stmt->fetch(); 

// get userid
$stmnt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT info FROM infos WHERE userid = :r");
$stmnt2->execute(["r" => $r['id']]);
```

I am struggling to get all the info id and info based on the userid. I have managed to get the info but it misses out the first entry and I can't get the infoid

```
    // get info based on userid
    if ($info = $stmnt2->fetch()) {
        echo '<p>Your Info:</p>';   
            while ($info = $stmnt2->fetch()) {
            echo "$info[info] </br>";
            }
   } else {
        echo "<p>No Info</p>";
```

Can someone tell me how I can get infoid and info to be shown thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
// get userid
$stmnt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT info FROM infos WHERE userid = :r");
$stmnt2->execute(["r" => $r['id']]);
```

with

```
// get userid
$stmnt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT info, infoid AS id FROM infos WHERE userid = :r");
$stmnt2->execute(["r" => $r['id']]);
```

and replace

```
// get info based on userid
if ($info = $stmnt2->fetch()) {
    echo '<p>Your Info:</p>';   
        while ($info = $stmnt2->fetch()) {
        echo "$info[info] </br>";
        }
} else {
    echo "<p>No Info</p>";
}
```

with

```
// get info based on userid

if ($info = $stmnt2->fetch()) {
    echo '<p>Your Info:</p>';   
    do {
        echo "$info[info] </br>"; //The info id is contained in the $info['id']
    } while ($info = $stmnt2->fetch());
} else {
    echo "<p>No Info</p>";
}
```

or

```
// get info based on userid

if ($stmnt2->num_rows()) {
    echo '<p>Your Info:</p>';   
    while ($info = $stmnt2->fetch()){
        echo "$info[info] </br>"; //The info id is contained in the $info['id']
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>No Info</p>";
}
```

I would suggest you the second way. Do not hesitate to ask me for any explanation.

Comment: Thank you it is working. PS. I am using sqlite so num_rows would be fetch

Comment: `->num_rows()` is the number of rows returned by the query but `->fetch()` gives you the row in the query, not sure if that is really it, but i'm not sure for SQLLite

Comment: num_rows() does not work for me as I am using PDO and when I use rowCount which I think is its alternative I get the output "No Info". So I've stuck with the first one as that works

Comment: Ok, that is also why i posted both ways